# Why are my two recent comments deleted?

Tags: support, comments

I don’t understand why my comment in [How to write this in latex](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/350164/261469) and [Translating the system into latex](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/350161/261469) were deleted (I don’t see there anymore). What is false with these additional helpful information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

See [Help Centre](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

That is they can and will be deleted at any time. The point of a comment is to improve the question or answer. If they contain relevant information then that information should be edited into the question or answer. stack Exchange is a collection of questions and answers anything else is just a tool to help improve these

Comment: So, I can edit the question from other user and link to the tex.stackexchange site where the same question was posted by other user?

Comment: Yes, anyone can edit any question or answer. As you have less than 200 reputation then your edits will have to be approved try other users.

Comment: Although reading the questions they are duplicates and no attempt has been made to show what Latex was attempted so should be closed on any site.

Comment: And, as written, they are definitively not related to Apple products and their use. But even if the OP would be using TeX on macOS I would probably migrate it to TeX.SE as the answer required (La)TeX knowhow

Answer (score 5):

Thank you so much for posting here on meta. This is the place to discuss migrations and not in comments. I deleted the comments since the question isn’t one I would migrate anywhere due to quality issues. Leaving the migration path open is confusing to people when the main message is - this isn’t a good question, quality wise.  Once it’s edited to meet minimum quality, then we would entertain comments or flags or questions to migrate.

That a poor question was cross posted twice should be discouraged, so the moderation team will engage with the asker as part of the normal moderation process.

Most importantly, thank you for being involved and asking for clarification!